# GRADLE - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource

Tags: java, spring, gradle, sonarqube, build.gradle

I am trying to set up SonarQube in my local machine. While running the command - `gradle sonarqube <params>`, I get the below error - ***Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource***

Tried including `compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1'` in the build.gradle for MOSModels but that didn't help. Any help is appreciated.

- System java version - JDK 11
- Project Java version - JDK 8
- Gradle version - 5.0

  ```
   19:33:01.701 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] Execution worker [Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]] finished, busy: 1.17 secs, idle: 0.448 secs
   19:33:01.701 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph] Timing: Executing the DAG took 1.64 secs
   19:33:01.708 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run tasks'
   19:33:01.708 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Run tasks' completed
   19:33:01.713 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
   19:33:01.714 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
   19:33:01.714 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
   19:33:01.714 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
   19:33:01.714 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':MOSModels:xjc'.
   19:33:01.714 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
   19:33:01.714 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
   19:33:01.714 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
   19:33:01.715 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
   19:33:01.715 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
   19:33:01.715 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
   19:33:01.715 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':MOSModels:xjc'.
   19:33:01.716 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:96)
   19:33:01.716 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:65)
   19:33:01.716 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ActionEventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(ActionEventFiringTaskExecuter.java:44)
   19:33:01.716 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TimeoutTaskExecuter.execute(TimeoutTaskExecuter.java:53)
   19:33:01.716 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SnapshotAfterExecutionTaskExecuter.execute(SnapshotAfterExecutionTaskExecuter.java:38)
   19:33:01.716 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
   19:33:01.717 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
   19:33:01.717 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:49)
   19:33:01.717 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:61)
   19:33:01.717 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
   19:33:01.717 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
   19:33:01.717 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
   19:33:01.717 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
   19:33:01.717 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:55)
   19:33:01.717 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
   19:33:01.718 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:35)
   19:33:01.718 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
   19:33:01.718 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
   19:33:01.718 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
   19:33:01.718 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
   19:33:01.718 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
   19:33:01.718 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
   19:33:01.718 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:44)
   19:33:01.718 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
   19:33:01.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
   19:33:01.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
   19:33:01.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
   19:33:01.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
   19:33:01.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
   19:33:01.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
   19:33:01.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
   19:33:01.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
   19:33:01.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
   19:33:01.720 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
   19:33:01.720 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
   19:33:01.720 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
   19:33:01.720 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
   19:33:01.720 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
   19:33:01.720 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:78)
   19:33:01.720 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:103)
   19:33:01.720 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.jacobo.plugins.ant.AntXjc.execute(AntXjc.groovy:58)
   19:33:01.720 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   19:33:01.721 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   19:33:01.721 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   19:33:01.721 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.jacobo.plugins.task.JaxbXjc.xjc(JaxbXjc.groovy:131)
   19:33:01.721 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.jacobo.plugins.task.JaxbXjc$xjc$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
   19:33:01.721 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.jacobo.plugins.task.JaxbXjc.parseNode(JaxbXjc.groovy:124)
   19:33:01.721 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   19:33:01.721 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   19:33:01.721 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   19:33:01.722 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.jacobo.plugins.task.JaxbXjc$_start_closure1.doCall(JaxbXjc.groovy:107)
   19:33:01.722 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   19:33:01.722 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   19:33:01.722 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   19:33:01.722 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.jacobo.plugins.task.JaxbXjc.start(JaxbXjc.groovy:107)
   19:33:01.722 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   19:33:01.722 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   19:33:01.723 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   19:33:01.723 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
   19:33:01.723 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
   19:33:01.723 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
   19:33:01.723 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
   19:33:01.723 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:704)
   19:33:01.723 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:671)
   19:33:01.723 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:117)
   19:33:01.724 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
   19:33:01.724 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
   19:33:01.724 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
   19:33:01.724 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
   19:33:01.724 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
   19:33:01.724 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:106)
   19:33:01.725 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:85)
   19:33:01.725 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 35 more
   19:33:01.725 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
   19:33:01.726 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:461)
   19:33:01.726 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
   19:33:01.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
   19:33:01.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
   19:33:01.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156)
   19:33:01.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
   19:33:01.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:455)
   19:33:01.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
   19:33:01.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
   19:33:01.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1174)
   19:33:01.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
   19:33:01.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:286)
   19:33:01.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   19:33:01.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   19:33:01.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   19:33:01.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.inheritance.Customizations.<clinit>(Customizations.java:28)
   19:33:01.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.inheritance.InheritancePlugin.getCustomizationElementNames(InheritancePlugin.java:40)
   19:33:01.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.AbstractPlugin.getCustomizationURIs(AbstractPlugin.java:98)
   19:33:01.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArgument(Options.java:710)
   19:33:01.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArguments(Options.java:815)
   19:33:01.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task._doXJC(XJC2Task.java:468)
   19:33:01.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task.doXJC(XJC2Task.java:454)
   19:33:01.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task.execute(XJC2Task.java:379)
   19:33:01.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task.execute(XJC2Task.java:15)
   19:33:01.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
   19:33:01.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   19:33:01.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   19:33:01.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   19:33:01.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
   19:33:01.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 69 more
   19:33:01.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
   19:33:01.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1384)
   19:33:01.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1333)
   19:33:01.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1088)
   19:33:01.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 98 more
   19:33:01.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
   19:33:01.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
   19:33:01.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
   19:33:01.731 [WARN] [org.gradle.internal.featurelifecycle.LoggingDeprecatedFeatureHandler]
   Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
   See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
   19:33:01.731 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
   19:33:01.731 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 5s
  ```

Comment: `1.1.1` is the latest version of activation. Try that and see if it fixes the issue

Comment: Judging by your comment on my answer (which I have deleted), my educated guess didn't work. In that case, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @locus2k - That didn't help

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Not sure how I could provide one. I get this while I run the gradle sonarqube command - `gradle sonarqube -Dsonar.projectKey=<key> -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=1a47e089fd3ed8d773a0f8806c4e5cf52b5ba148 --stacktrace`. Moreoever, I have a multi gradle project and the error occurs in the one of the child project.

Comment: I am able to compile my project. And this error is thrown on running the gradle command as above, just fyi

Comment: Try putting the activation dependency into the [buildscript dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies) (using the `classpath` configuration)

Comment: @BjørnVester Had tried that as per Mark's suggestion but unfortunately didn't help